# Cox regression with two events

Tags: survival, cox-model

We have a status variable with three events:
0) Censored
1) Relapse
2) Death

We want to examine if two different types of medicine have a different risk on either death or relapse. How can we compare those two risks?
We use SPSS.

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you might need competing risk regression. R has capabilities for this - not sure about SPSS.

Comment: Hi Isabella! Thank you for your answer! Very helpful :)

Comment: Hi again :-)
I was just wondering - is there no other way to get around the competing risk situation?

Comment: You can't really 'get around' the competing risk situation. However, how you factor it into your regression modelling depends on your research question. See https://academic.oup.com/ndt/article/28/11/2670/1823847 and also https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3328633/ for details on how you might proceed.

Comment: Based on your research focus, you may need to choose between a proportional cause-specific hazards regression model or a subdistribution hazards regression model (unless you decide that both of them would provide useful information to you).

Comment: Okay, that is besides my statistic knowledge so far - I think I'll just go with the competing risk situaiton..
Thank you again :-)

Answer (score 0):

SPSS currently has no native procedures that handle competing risks.